# How to create a views block that lists all users who bought a product?

Tags: 7, views, users, ubercart

I need to create a list of users who purchased a product (uid & email) within that product page for administration so the Admin could have a list of them (using Views).

It is similar to how the Who Bought What module in Ubercart 3.x does but this is going to be a block placed at the bottom of each Product that lists only the users who purchased that specific product.

Comment: I have exactly this need also - did you ever find a solution? 
I'm looking into maybe just making a block with an iframe around the report. But that's hugely klunky. There has to be a better way.